# Yii Get Related Data into a GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii

My view lets the user see a person's details, including the families they are in. This is done in the DB with a Person table, Family table, and a familyMembership link table between the two.

The relationship in the CActiveRecord model for Person is as such:

```
'families' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Family', 'familymembership(Person, Family)'),
```

In my person controller, I am wanting to pass a variable into the view that has the related data in a way that TbGridView (CGridView but Bootstrap) will accept (a data provider). The controller calls the person model's getFamilies() function:

```
public function getFamilies() {
    // returns an array of Family objects related to this Person model
    $familiesArray = $this->getRelated('families');
    // puts this array into a CArrayDataProvider
    $families = new CArrayDataProvider($familiesArray);
    return $families;
}
```

The return value goes back to the controller, which is then handed through in the renderPartial() call. The view has a TbGridView widget initialisation like this:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', 
            array(
                //the CArrayDataProvider from the model function
                'dataProvider' => $families, 
                'columns' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Family Name',
                        // Example field from Family model
                        'value' => '$data->familyName' 
                    )
                )
        ));
```

However, in doing this I am getting the following error:
'Property "Family.id" is not defined. (D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php:130)'

The Family model does not have an id property, and I don't understand why the widget is looking for such.

What's going wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the doc from [Yii Class Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider), you have to provide a `keyField`:

> Elements in the raw data array may be either objects (e.g. model objects) or associative arrays (e.g. query results of DAO). Make sure to **set the keyField property to the name of the field that uniquely identifies a data record** or false if you do not have such a field.

By default `keyField` will be set to "id", so you need to overwrite it with your Family model primary key :

```
<?php
$familyDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'keyField' => 'yourPkNameHere',
));
```